# Create a simple JAR instead of an executable JAR with Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, spring-boot

I have a problem with a Multi-Module Spring-Boot Application.

I have one Module that I use for Services, the *core*-Module. And one module for View-Related Classes, the *web*-Module.
The are both in a *parent*-Module, where I add the dependencies, like the "spring-boot-starter" and that can be used by both modules.

Now to the problem:

I want to run the *web*-Module with the embedded Tomcat and have the *core*-Module as a dependency in the *web*-module.

In other Spring projects I would just include the *maven-jar-plugin* and create a jar of the *core*-Module.

The problem in this Spring-Boot project is that the *maven-jar-plugin* is already configured, in the "spring-boot-starter". And it needs a mainClass, which only the *web*-module has.

Small excerpt from the "spring-boot-starter"-POM

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Is there a way to package the *core*-Module as a JAR without needing a "start-class" in that module?

Comment: If you search for [`spring boot non executable jar`](https://www.google.com/#q=spring+boot+non+executable+jar), you will find [Create a non-executable JAR with exclusions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-a-nonexecutable-jar) in the Spring Boot documentation.

Comment: @Andreas The problem is that this still needs the mainClass-Attribute. Since the configuration is in the Spring-files. I attached the Spring-Configuration in the original question.

Answer (score 8):

It seem like you can disable the fat-JAR from replacing the original and getting installed into the repo by configuring the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Taken from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-disable-attach.html:

> By default, the repackage goal will replace the original artifact with
>   the executable one. If you need to only deploy the original jar and
>   yet be able to run your app with the regular file name, configure the
>   plugin as follows:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <attach>false</attach>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        ...
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

> This configuration will generate two artifacts: the original one and the executable counter part produced by the repackage goal. Only the original one will be installed/deployed.

Comment: Perfect solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can just disable the spring-boot-maven plugin this way.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer.
I configured my application just like @judgingnotjudging explained. The difference was that I had put this, in the *parent*-POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It was preventing the default creation of JARs in the children-modules. I could resolve this problem by including this **only** in the *web*-Module.

That way Spring-Boot builds a fat-JAR from the *web*-Module and a simple JAR from the *core*-Module.

Answer (score 2):

To create simple jar update

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

To

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

For more details please visit below Spring URL:-
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-build.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

to

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.0</version>
```

Comment: Not including the magic maven plugin seems to be a simple solution that worked for me.

Comment: I removed the entire plugin and it worked for me too. I ran mvn package command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's still relevant or not, however, a simple classifier needs to be configured for the spring-boot-maven-plugin -

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This would generate two jars - one a normal one which can be included as a dependency, another as an exe jar with the "exec" word appended as a suffix - like test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar and test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the embedded tomcat to run your app, don't you just want a standard Spring Boot fat jar for your web app? If so, just mark your web module as dependent on your core module in the pom, and build your project.

It's there a different use case that you need the jars separated?

Are you building your modules as completely separate modules or as modules as part of a single multi-module project? The difference is in the latter, you will have a pom at the root specifying the modules. I forget the Maven syntax specifically, so my example is Gradle (Maven docs for multi-module builds are [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)). Sorry about that.

```
baseProject
|----web-module
|----core-module
```

baseProject's build.gradle:

```
project(':web-module') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core-module')
    }
    evaluationDependsOn(':core-module')

}
```

Maven has a similar structure. You should review the docs, but I believe all you need to do is specify the module order correctly in your parent pom as below and include the dependency in your web-module pom.

Parent pom:

```
...
<modules>
    <module>core-module</module>
    <module>web-module</module>
</modules>
```

web-pom:

```
<project ...>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>web-module</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>My web-module</name>
<dependencies>

...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

core pom should only need to include the `parent` section as in the web-module above, and otherwise be the same.

Comment: I want to use the _web_-module to be the fat-JAR and have the _core_-module as a dependency. To have the _core_-module as a dependency, I need to be able to create a "product" that can be installed in the .m2-directory. Maybe there's an easier way of achieving this.

Comment: @Johannes Esseling I updated my answer to include building a multi-module project. It sounds like you're expecting to publish your core-module to the repository then retrieve it. You can avoid that by creating the project as a multi-module project.